# Django not connecting to postgres db. port 5432 failed: FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I have a database called postgres. However when trying to connect it gives the following error output: port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist. If i change to template1 it works but i want to use postgres.

List of databases:

```
Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------
postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |            | libc            |
template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
          |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
          |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Django settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': 5432,

 }
}
```

Please note i am using Docker. docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
db:
image: postgres
volumes:
  - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
environment:
  - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
web:
build: .
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
volumes:
  - .:/code
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
depends_on:
  - db
volumes:
postgres_data:
```

Comment: 1) Why do you want to connect to `postgres`? You should be using your own created database for Django application. 2) **Do not use images, copy and paste text into question**. 3) Try connecting with `psql`. 4) I suspect you are connecting to different Postgres clusters in each case.

Comment: I have tried creating a new database, however my django project still cannot establish a connection. it throws the same error message. Can you explain point no.4? I did reinstall postgresql. Maybe my project is looking for the old version of postgres in the previous installation?

Comment: 1) Use `psql` and try and connect to the database, either `postgres` or the new one, and add complete error message to your question. 2) How did you get the list of databases?

Comment: You probably have multiple database servers running and are connecting to different ones at different times.  Docker environments can be confusing about which host is which.  Also, your docker-compose.yml file is not valid.

Comment: I have edited the docker-compose file. Please see above. Is there a way i can check which server it is using?